# jQuery - Assign label text

Tags: jquery

jQuery 1.7.1 - I have an array of input text elements (class - pr) and same number of array elements for label (class - err). I have some validation on blur of the text box and would like to assign a error message to the label associated with the text box. The following jQuery code is not working.

**HTML**

```
<tr>
   <td>
            <label class="err" style="display: none;" for="prd"></label> 
            <input type="text" class="pr" name="prd" />
    </td>
 </tr>
```

**jQuery**

```
$("input.pr:text").blur(function(event){
    // .... validation code
    var index = $.inArray(this, $("input.pr:text"));
    $("label.err")[index].show();
    $("label.err")[index].text("Enter a number");
 });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One liner:

```
$('label.err').eq(index).show().text('Enter a number');
```

or probably better:

```
$("input.pr:text").blur(function(event){
     $(this).prev('label').show().text("Enter a number");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Once you reference a JQuery object using the index, it's no longer a JQuery object but a plain DOM element.  Use the following instead:

```
var el = $($("label.err")[index]);
el.show();
el.text("Enter a number");
```